# How to watch youtube in a less cpu intensive way using raspberry pi?

Tags: video, cpu, hdmi, raspberry-pi, youtube

I have a pi 3 with `raspbian` installed. It is primarily used to work as a torrent box and serve the videos I download over `samba`. But it is connected to a tv over hdmi also. I was wondering if there is a way to stream `youtube` videos while connected to tv in a less CPU intensive way. When I use chromium, and start a 720p video, the CPU spikes from less than 10% to 100%, temperature rise from 50 degrees to 80 degrees making the video to lag.It is similar while using other browsers also. Tried using `kodi` , its better than browsers, but it displays black screen after exit, requiring me to force restart. There are some less tech savvy users (my flatmates) also want to use this, so I am looking for a better solution. Also, I prefer not to switch to a media centric distro.

Comment: Do you use `kodi` on top of a window manager? or `kodi-standalone`? The latter may perform better. My friend has an older model of Pi with `raspbian` and he used to run a script that started `kodi-standalone`, then desktop after `kodi` terminated, then `kodi-standalone` after the desktop exited – and so on.

Comment: `kodi` will not work at all, `kodi-standalone` works sometimes. But it is not reliable to use.